# Java round a decimal up to the next highest int

Tags: java, rounding

In Java, how can I round a decimal to the next highest int?
So that 3.1 would become 4, 4.6 becomes 5, 4.5 becomes 5, 1.004 becomes 2, etc...
This probably a silly question but I can't figure it out...

Sorry for this being a duplicate. I spent about an hour on google and 15 min on here trying be find it but I only got the normal rounding (1.5 -> 2, 1.2 -> 1) so I figured I may as well ask.

Comment: The duplicate points to a solution for double. OP is asking for decimal (BigDecimal?).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.ceil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29). This will round up to nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int roundedNum = (int) Math.ceil(decimalNum);
     /* where decimalNum should be a double */
```